# how to set RequiredFieldValidator to validate against specific user control which has multiple instance?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, user-controls, requiredfieldvalidator

so let say i have a user control which called 7 times in an aspx file, i put field validator control in that user control, the problem is everytime i click some buttons which cause postback, field validator always validate controls against all instances of my user control, what i want is to validate against specific user control, i have tried this :

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="DateNew" CssClass="time" Width="185px"/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Date can not be empty" ControlToValidate="DateNew" ValidationGroup='<%= ClientID %>' Text="*"> </asp:RequiredFieldValidator> 
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="NewSchedule" Text="Schedule" CssClass="bgrey" 
        OnClientClick="CheckKeyValues()" OnClick="NewSchedule_Click"  ValidationGroup='<%= ClientId %>'/>
```

this is not working... any correction? thanx before. btw some example would be great.

update : aspx file with a user control called 7 times

```
 <asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                        </asp:ScriptManager>
                        <div id="divError" class="n fail" style="display:none; margin:15px; width:2330px">
                             <h5>
                                The following errors were found
                             </h5>
                             <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary" runat="server" />
                        </div>    
                        <div class="warea clearfix" style="width: 2350px">
                            <div style="float:left;">
                                <uc1:ucApplicationProgress runat="server" id="ucApplicationProgress" TestType="Interview 1" />
                            </div>
                             <div style="float:left;">
                                <uc1:ucApplicationProgress runat="server" id="ucApplicationProgress1" TestType="Interview 2"/>
                            </div>
                             <div style="float:left;">
                               <uc1:ucApplicationProgress runat="server" id="ucApplicationProgress2" TestType="Interview 3"/>
                            </div>
                             <div style="float:left;">
                                <uc1:ucApplicationProgress runat="server" id="ucApplicationProgress3" TestType="English Test"/>
                            </div>
                             <div style="float:left;">
                                <uc1:ucApplicationProgress runat="server" id="ucApplicationProgress4" TestType="Medical Examination"/>
                            </div>
                             <div style="float:left;">
                                <uc1:ucApplicationProgress runat="server" id="ucApplicationProgress5" TestType="Internal Psycho Test"/>
                            </div>
                             <div style="float:left;">
                                <uc1:ucApplicationProgress runat="server" id="ucApplicationProgress6" TestType="External Psycho Test"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

user control file :

```
 <h3><asp:Label runat="server" ID="TypeNew"/></h3>
              <table>
                  <tr>
                     <td>Date</td>
                     <td>
                         <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="DateNew" CssClass="time" Width="185px"/>
                         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Date can not be empty" ControlToValidate="DateNew">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>Time</td>
                      <td>
                          <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="HourNew"  Width="40px"/> 
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Time can not be empty" ControlToValidate="HourNew" Text="*">
                          </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>:  
                          <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="MinuteNew"  Width="40px"/>
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Minute can not be empty" ControlToValidate="MinuteNew" Text="*">
                          </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>Location</td>
                      <td>
                          <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="LocationNew" TextMode="MultiLine"/>
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Location can not be empty" ControlToValidate="LocationNew" Text="*">
                          </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>Interviewer</td>
                      <td>
                          <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="InterviewerNew" autocomplete="off" onchange="MarkFlag(this.id)"/>
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Interviewer can not be empty" ControlToValidate="InterviewerNew" Text="*">
                          </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                          <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="InterviewerKeys"/>
                          <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="InterviewerEmail"/>    
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                      <td><asp:Button runat="server" ID="NewSchedule" Text="Schedule" CssClass="bgrey" OnClientClick="CheckKeyValues()" OnClick="NewSchedule_Click" /></td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
```

C# :

```
 public String ValidationGroup
        {
            get 
            { 
                return RequiredFieldValidator1.ValidationGroup;
            }
            set
            {
                RequiredFieldValidator1.ValidationGroup = value;
                RequiredFieldValidator2.ValidationGroup = value;
                RequiredFieldValidator3.ValidationGroup = value;
                RequiredFieldValidator4.ValidationGroup = value;
                RequiredFieldValidator5.ValidationGroup = value;
                NewSchedule.ValidationGroup = value;
            }
        }


  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                ValidationGroup = this.ID;
        }
```

Comment: Validate using Usercontrol id.

Comment: ValidationGroup='<%= ClientId %>'/> is n't it to get user control client id?

Comment: Assign validationgroup as static one.

Comment: if i assign static id, all the user control instance will get the same id.

Comment: For example Assign Validationgroup="v1". In Codebehind you can validate specific usercontrol by its id and then you can assign that validation control enabled as false(reqfield.enabled=false;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expose a property on your Web User Control named ValidationGroup:

```
public String ValidationGroup
{
    get { return RequiredFieldValidator1.ValidationGroup; }
    set { 
        RequiredFieldValidator1.ValidationGroup = value; 
        NewSchedule.ValidationGroup = value; 
    }
}
```

Then set it to a unique value for each instance you create on your web form.

Comment: so after i updated my post, now my validation summary which used to get all validation message and located in aspx file, does not show at all.

Comment: I don't see where you are setting the ValidationGroup on the user controls in your .aspx page.

Comment: i put it in the page_load "ValidationGroup = this.ID;"

Comment: What is CheckKeyValues() doing?

Comment: Checkkeyvalues() is my javascript function, i created in for jquery quto complete function.

Comment: are you sure that's not disabling the vaidation?  I tested my code with a simple page that used 4 instances of my usercontrol.  i set the validation group in the .aspx code and it worked fine.

Comment: yeah.. i tried to remove that function, but still my validation control does not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Give the validation group value anything like "Name" as i have given.
And add the same validation group to both controls on which validation is to be fired and the control whose post back should fir validation.

```
     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Name"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
        ErrorMessage="Field value is required" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" 
        ValidationGroup="Name"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="Name" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

As in this case TextBox1 validation fires only when Button1 is clicked not on Button2 click event.

Comment: thanx, but this is not what i want to achieve, you miss understand it. "i want to validate against specific user control" not server control.